# Android: copy or move files with uri path

Tags: android, path, copy, uri

I am writing an app, in which you can open multiple image files. Once loaded, you can select a subset of these images and then you should be able to copy or move the selected images to a new location.

I am using ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for file and folder selection.

Unfortunately, I am struggeling with the actual copy and move operations.

```
    File x = new File(uri.getPath())
```

does not work, as the path is in wrong format.

Additionally I tried something like

```
 DocumentsContract.copyDocument(contentResolver, fileUri, folderUri)
```

but this did not work either.

Does anybody have an idea?

I am adding some basic code (scaled down to a minimum (also one file only))

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.ich.demonstrator">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sel_file_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select File"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sel_folder_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Folder"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>
     </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the main Activity

```
  package org.ich.demonstrator;
  
  import android.Manifest;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  
  import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
  
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  
      Button selFile;
      Button selFolder;
      ImageView imgView;
      Uri file;
  
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
          initFileAccess();
  
          selFile = findViewById(R.id.sel_file_button);
          selFolder = findViewById(R.id.sel_folder_button);
          imgView = findViewById(R.id.img_view);
  
          selFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent().setType("image/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                  //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 123);
  
              }
          });
  
          selFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, 345);
              }
          });
      }
  
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          try {
              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                  switch (requestCode) {
                      case 345: {
                          if (data != null) {
                              Uri uri = data.getData();
                              if (uri != null) {
                                  System.out.println("Folder : "+uri.getPath());
                                  /******************************
                                   *
                                   *   Here: Copy or Move Image to selected Folder
                                   *
                                   *****************************/
                              }
                          }
                          break;
                      }
                      case 123: {
                          if (data != null) {
                              Uri uri = data.getData();
                              if (uri != null) {
                                  System.out.println("File : "+uri.getPath());
                                  imgView.setImageURI(uri);
                                  file = uri;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              //Do Nothing
          }
      }
  
      private void initFileAccess() {
          int writeExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
          if (writeExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 42);
          }
      }
  
  }
```